# Call JSON object on page load event in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, webforms

How to call json object on page load event in ASP.Net. I have created a json object

```
jsonObject = {"rooms": [{
                    "adult": adult.val(), "child": child.val()
                }]}
```

on a page at client side, then i am passing this object to another page like this :

```
var w = window.open("Default.aspx");
w.myVariable = jsonObject;
```

I am able to get the JsonObject in Default.aspx page on Client side by

```
 var jsonObject = window.opener.jsonObject.rooms
```

but i want to call this Object on page load event of Default.aspx page at server. Something like this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//var jsonobject = jsonObject;
}
```

Please can someone explain me how to achieve this. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of doing this using the .Net System.Web.Script.Serialization class.

Simple shopping cart example. The JSON string is deserialized and added to a ShoppingCart object. Now using a Generic List (newItem) you can use your strongly typed JSON values any way you want server side.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ShoppingCart>(json);

    List<ShoppingCart> newItem = new List<ShoppingCart>();
    newItem.Add(new ShoppingCart(jsonObj.ProductId,
                                 jsonObj.ProductTitle,
                                 jsonObj.DefaultImagePath,
                                 jsonObj.Quantity,
                                 jsonObj.Price,
                                 jsonObj.Total);

}
```